# Webflow for GCP login

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there a Go implementation of GCP Webflow similar to what gcloud SDK does (https://github.com/twistedpair/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/flow.py)?

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2 (with [golang.org/x/oauth2/google.ConfigFromJSON](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#ConfigFromJSON))

Comment: The docs have no mention of `ConfigFromJSON` to implement webflow for oauth2. I could not find any implementation in all of oauth2.

Comment: Redirect to the URL returned by [Config.AuthCodeURL](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.AuthCodeURL).  In your redirect handler validate the state and call [Config.Exchange](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Exchange), then use [the client](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Client).

Comment: @Peter Can you please post your comment as an answer to help out the community?

Answer (score 0):

this [repo](https://github.com/salrashid123/oauth2oidc) relies on printing a url in console and letting user to copy/paste Auth Code instead of automatically launching browser and running a local server like gcloud SDK does, but it's README is worth a read as it also shows you current limitations when using Oauth/openid connect flow to authenticate to Cloud Run.

If python is okay for you, there's an official python [lib](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/blob/master/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py#L322) that supports launching browser and running a local server, like what gcloud sdk does.